# HOw Can i Get the rain fall % of previous day in yii

Tags: php, yii, weather, noaa

Helli , I am using yii framwork and i want to show a rain fall event on the graph if there was any rainfall . but I don't know how to get the previous data . I have used the noaa yii extension to get the weather forcast data but no result https://github.com/markscarbrough/noaaWeather. I am using like this

```
$summaryDataProvider = Yii::createComponent(
    'ext.noaaWeather.NoaaForecastSummaryDataProvider',
    array('coordinates'=>array(
        'latitude' => 44.27,
        'longitude' => -71.3,
        ))  
    );
$weather = $summaryDataProvider->getData();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($weather);
```

please help

Comment: no error but i got the forecast data i need the data for the past hour

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of what the output looks like?

Comment: Did you follow your own links to the documentation? The examples suggest using days and offset parameters. At least convince us that you have read this and tried this out.

Comment: i have used everything to get the rain fall data but it i am failed , It us showing only the future weather data.But i need total rain fall in the past hour , day, month, year on the graph .